# App to read pgn surface

Tags: engines, pgn

Is there anyway to read pgn's on the surface 2 (windows 8), besides using any online tool for that matter.

Comment: Download any number of chess interfaces such as scid?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows desktop there is [ChessX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chessx/) and for a modern / metro app there is [PgnViewer](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-gb/app/pgnviewer/c8016498-a479-4a02-a10b-fd452f06e7c5)

Comment: Thanks for you answer :), btw chessX also works for mac, it is the software I am using now.